# Memory increase with no release memory

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, memory-leaks

I search how find my problem.
In my application for iPad when i treat data i have an increase memory and never release that memory, i try instruments leaks memory but that not find memory leaks (i try with profile and analyze).

So my question is they have an other instrument for find memory leaks or other methods?

Thanks in advance for your consideration.

P.S : I don't post code cause that concerned a big part of my code but the part where memory increase is a part where i download from a FTP some zip files (based on SimpleFTPSample from Apple Doc) i unzip this files (with framework minizip) this zip files contains some images and XML files i parse this XML files (around 7200 XML files and 35 000 images files saved) i saved some information (issue of parsing) in data base and that its. If you need part of my code for help me ask me.

Comment: Like you said yourself: there are no leaks.   You need to stop allocating things in a tight loop.

Comment: You said you're downloading and paring 7,200 XML files.  I assume you'd be using a loop.

Comment: Sure i have a loop but how stop allocating, i release all my object that i create and i used @autoreleasepool for other object but thats not release all memory in used so i don't understand why this increase  when i check memory with instruments...

Comment: Do your files in chunks.  When you're done with one set of data (perhaps 50-100 files), clean up after yourself, store it, release some memory, then load the next chunk.

Comment: I try this too but not work i think my problem is more under this cause when my treatment is finish i have a big memory and that stabilize the memory for more clear before all my treatment i have a memory to 30MB at the end i have a memory to 150MB and just not change but instrument doesn't detect memory leak that so strange no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure if you have Zombies turned off in Scheme:Diagnostics. With Zombies on no memory is ever deleted. Testing for memory leakage should always be done with Zombies off.

Comment: Damn i have Zombies on but that just on for mode run or that influence Profile mode too? (I am little newbie with this instruments...) I try to check leak memory with Zombie off.

Comment: @user1770436 Lol, that would explain it. By default, Profile uses the same configuration as Run. You can check that in "Product->Edit Scheme..." in XCode. You'll see that the Profile scheme uses the Run build configuration.

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when you keep the objects in a datastructure (NSDictionary, NSArray, eg), even after you don't need them anymore. Check with Instruments' Allocations which objects are accumulated, and check in your code where you keep instances of those objects.

Another cause could be long-running threads.
If the loading and parsing you mentioned are done in a single thread that takes a long time, then you may need to do [@autoreleasepool](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAutoreleasePools.html) in a loop somewhere to force temporary objects to be cleaned up regularly.

It might also be no problem at all. You say you load a lot of images. Images are by default cached by iOS, and only released when necessary to clean up memory. If Instruments "Trace Highlights" shows a lot of memory usage, but "Allocations" doesn't, then this is likely the cause.

Comment: This happen even though i release NSArray, NSDictionary etc..? If i place to nil this object after release that resolved my problem? Cause i have a lot of NSArray and NSDictionary so your explication have a good sense for me.

Comment: No. If you release the datastructures, then their members will also be released (unless they are referenced from somewhere else as well).

Comment: Normally i have a good alloc and release cause Analyze doesn't catch problem of leak so i think this good (or instruments of Xcode are bad ^^).

Comment: If Instruments Leaks does not report leaks, you most likely do not have leaks. But a "leak" means an object you have retained, but is not referenced anymore. But you can still have retained objects that you don't need anymore, but still reference from some datastructure. Run Instruments Allocations as I said, to see which objects are retained which you would not expect to be retained.

Comment: Thanks for your help i am in test (thats so long to download 700Mo and parse 7200 xml file + saved 35 000 image) with Profile leak (so with allocation too) and i have place Zombies in off like ahwulf says and apparently my memory is released so apparently the no release memory is caused by NSZombies option i wait the end of test for say victory but thats in good way.